# Python - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QueryFrame'

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm really new to OpenCV but I need to find a way to detect faces using a webcam. I have found following code from [here](http://www.lucaamore.com/?p=638). This is the original code. I'm using `Python 2.7` and `opencv 3.0.0-beta` version and Windows 8.1.

```
import cv2 as cv
import time
import Image

def DetectFace(image, faceCascade):

    min_size = (20,20)
    image_scale = 2
    haar_scale = 1.1
    min_neighbors = 3
    haar_flags = 0

    grayscale = cv.CreateImage((image.width, image.height), 8, 1)
    smallImage = cv.CreateImage(
            (
                cv.Round(image.width / image_scale),
                cv.Round(image.height / image_scale)
            ), 8 ,1)

    cv.CvtColor(image, grayscale, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.Resize(grayscale, smallImage, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR)
    cv.EqualizeHist(smallImage, smallImage)

    faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(
            smallImage, faceCascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0),
            haar_scale, min_neighbors, haar_flags, min_size)

    if faces:
        for ((x, y, w, h), n) in faces:
            pt1 = (int(x * image_scale), int(y * image_scale))
            pt2 = (int((x + w) * image_scale), int((y + h) * image_scale))
            cv.Rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, cv.RGB(255, 0, 0), 5, 8, 0)

    return image

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
faceCascade = cv.Load("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")

while (cv.WaitKey(15)==-1):
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    image = DetectFace(img, faceCascade)
    cv.ShowImage("face detection test", image)

cv.ReleaseCapture(capture)
```

When I was running this program I've got errors saying, No module named **Image**. I commented it and run again and did following changes to the code.

`capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)` to `capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)` and 
`WaitKey` to `waitKey` according to the errors popped up.

But now it says **`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QueryFrame'`**

I think there is a version problem or something. I've already included `haarcascades` files as well. Please help me to correct that error and run this code well. As I mention I'm a fresher to opencv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `cv2`, you use:

```
result, img = capture.read()  #capture is a cv2.VideoCapture instance
```

instead of `QueryFrame`.

You can also queue a frame for capture using

```
capture.grab()
```

followed by

```
result, img = capture.retrieve()
```

to actually retrieve it.  Use this second method if you want to queue up a frame, then do other stuff while you wait for it.

Edit:

You clearly are just trying to run a bunch of OpenCV1 functions using OpenCV2, and are going to have a lot of problems if you don't read the [OpenCV2 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html) to know what functions have changed and what hasn't.  StackOverflow isn't a "convert this old code" service, so I'm not going to go through every single old function in your program.

However, to answer your follow up question, in OpenCV2 it is recommended to just create images using the `numpy.zeros()` function (as opposed to the old `cv.CreateImage` function).

Comment: I've changed as you said, But now it says `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateImage'` I googled this but I don't have any idea what is this about.

Comment: Well, you are running `CreateImage` in your `DetectFace` function, which means that you have successfully gotten past your image acquisition issue, which means that I've answered your original question.  I'll edit my answer with a little more info.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark it answered. I do it just now. Help me to find that error too.

Answer (score 0):

cv2 does not have a method QueryFrame, it is located in cv.

```
import cv
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
```

Comment: Originally that code was written using `cv` But when I run it, it says `no module named cv` Then I changed it to `import cv2 as cv`